# clearInterval SetInterval function not defined

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I am trying to pause and restart a timer in a message box as the message box is updated every 10 seconds with a `setInterval`... I have managed to get a working `setInterval` timer working with a pause and restart when I press any key, but I see a way to use the functions being called for a click of a edit and save div and this would work great if I could code it correctly. As then when the edit button is clicked the `setInterval` could be paused and then when the save button is clicked the `setInterval` could restart.

However the code I have at present allows me to pause the timer , but when I click the save div I get a error, stating ticker is not defined... I'm not sure as to why this is, but from the code below can anybody see where I am going wrong, and why is the edit button pausing the timer but not the save button... Why is the save button not recognizing the timer?

Here is the code.

```
var myTimer;

$(function() {
  function ticker() {
    var varLISTID = "<?php echo $listID; ?>";
    var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $useraccountname; ?>";
    var varITEMACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $itemaccountname; ?>";
    var varSELECTEDUSER = document.getElementById('datacatchuser').getAttribute("data-variable-SELECTEDUSER");

    var mybutton = "messageboxreplybutton.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
    $('#buttonbox').load(mybutton);

    var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
    $('#infobox1').load(mylink);

    var myotherlink = "contactselect.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
    $('#containercontact').load(myotherlink);

    console.log("timer fired 2sec")
  }

  var myTimer = setInterval(ticker, 10000);

});

function editBuyermessage(messageid) {

  var varmessageid = messageid; //the div holding the data var
  var varmessageID = document.getElementById('Buyer' + varmessageid + '').getAttribute("data-variable-messageID"); //the id in the database
  var varMESSAGEDATE = document.getElementById('Buyer' + varmessageid + '').getAttribute("data-variable-MESSAGEDATE"); //message's senders username 
  var varLISTID = "<?php echo $listID; ?>";
  var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $useraccountname; ?>";
  var varITEMACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $itemaccountname; ?>";
  var varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('Buyer' + varmessageid + '').getAttribute("data-variable-MESSAGEACCOUNTNAME"); //message's senders username 
  var varSELECTEDUSER = document.getElementById('datacatchuser').getAttribute("data-variable-SELECTEDUSER");

  if (varUSERACCOUNTNAME == varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME) {

    var ebm = document.getElementById('editBuyer' + varmessageid + '');

    if ($(ebm).attr("contentEditable") == "false") {
      $('#editBuyer' + varmessageid + '').prop('contenteditable', true);
      $('#editBuyer' + varmessageid + '').css('outline', '0px');
      $('#editBuyer' + varmessageid + '').css('border', '1px dashed #07f310');
      $('#boxBEDIT' + varmessageid + '').text('Save');

      //here the timer is paused if the edit button is clicked//

      console.log("Paused for Typing")
      clearInterval(myTimer);

    } else {
      $('#editBuyer' + varmessageid + '').prop('contenteditable', false);
      $('#editBuyer' + varmessageid + '').css('outline', '0px');
      $('#editBuyer' + varmessageid + '').css('border', '1px solid transparent');
      $('#boxBEDIT' + varmessageid + '').text('Edit');

      //here the timer is restarted if the save button is pressed - but throws error
      clearInterval(myTimer);
      myTimer = setInterval(ticker, 10000);

      var gotmessage = $('#editBuyer' + varmessageid + '').text();
      var regex = /fuck|cunt|slag|bitch|fukker|nonce|prick|bollocks|dick|shag|slut|bastard|fuk|spunk|shit|wank/gi;
      gotmessage = gotmessage.replace(regex, "****");
      var Buyer = "Buyer";

      if (gotmessage != "") {

        $.ajax({

          url: "insertedit.php",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'text',
          cache: false,

          data: {
            BuyerSeller: Buyer,
            messageID: varmessageID,
            messagesent: gotmessage,
            listID: varLISTID,
            messageDate: varMESSAGEDATE,
            useraccountname: varUSERACCOUNTNAME,
          },
          async: true,

          success: function(data) {

            var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
            $('#infobox1').load(mylink);

            var myotherlink = "contactselect.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
            $('#containercontact').load(myotherlink);

          }
        });

      } // if gotmessage not empty
      else {
        alert('Empty Message - Not Sent');
        return false;
      }
    }

  } else {
    alert("Sorry You Cannot Edit " + varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME + "'s Message!");
  }
}

function editSellermessage(messageid) {

  var varmessageid = messageid; //the div holding the data var

  var varmessageID = document.getElementById('Seller' + varmessageid + '').getAttribute("data-variable-messageID"); //the id in the database
  var varMESSAGEDATE = document.getElementById('Seller' + varmessageid + '').getAttribute("data-variable-MESSAGEDATE"); //message's senders username 
  var varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('Seller' + varmessageid + '').getAttribute("data-variable-MESSAGEACCOUNTNAME"); //message's senders username 
  var varSELECTEDUSER = document.getElementById('datacatchuser').getAttribute("data-variable-SELECTEDUSER");
  var varLISTID = "<?php echo $listID; ?>";
  var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $useraccountname; ?>";
  var varITEMACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $itemaccountname; ?>";

  if (varUSERACCOUNTNAME == varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME) {

    var ebm = document.getElementById('editSeller' + varmessageid + '');

    if ($(ebm).attr("contentEditable") == "false") {
      $('#editSeller' + varmessageid + '').prop('contenteditable', true);
      $('#editSeller' + varmessageid + '').css('outline', '0px');
      $('#editSeller' + varmessageid + '').css('border', '1px dashed #07f310');
      $('#boxSEDIT' + varmessageid + '').text('Save');

      //pause timer if edit buytton pressed

      console.log("Paused for Typing")
      clearInterval(myTimer);

    } else {

      //restart timer if save button is pressed - but throws error

      clearInterval(myTimer);
      var myTimer = setInterval(ticker, 10000);

      $('#editSeller' + varmessageid + '').prop('contenteditable', false);
      $('#editSeller' + varmessageid + '').css('outline', '0px');
      $('#editSeller' + varmessageid + '').css('border', '1px solid transparent');
      $('#boxSEDIT' + varmessageid + '').text('Edit');

      var gotmessage = $('#editSeller' + varmessageid + '').text();
      var regex = /fuck|cunt|slag|bitch|fukker|nonce|prick|bollocks|dick|shag|slut|bastard|fuk|spunk|shit|wank/gi;
      gotmessage = gotmessage.replace(regex, "****");
      var Seller = "Seller";

      if (gotmessage != "") {

        $.ajax({

          url: "insertedit.php",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'text',
          cache: false,

          data: {
            BuyerSeller: Seller,
            messageID: varmessageID,
            messagesent: gotmessage,
            listID: varLISTID,
            messageDate: varMESSAGEDATE,
            useraccountname: varUSERACCOUNTNAME,
            sendto: varSELECTEDUSER,
          },
          async: true,

          success: function(data) {

            var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
            $('#infobox1').load(mylink);


          }
        });

      } // if gotmessage not empty
      else {
        alert('Empty Message - Not Sent');
        return false;
      }
    }

  } else {
    alert("Sorry You Cannot Edit " + varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME + "'s Message!");
  }

}
```

Comment: `ticker` is defined within the `$(function(){` function. Is there a reason it's defined locally? Can't you just move it outside to broaden the scope?

Comment: its within a $function so it is automatically called to update the messagebox

Comment: how is  //here the timer is paused if the edit button is clicked//

                      console.log("Paused for Typing")
                        clearInterval(myTimer);   in scope ???  im confused

Comment: can u think of another way to automatically call the ticker function without the $function

Comment: Again, can't you just define `ticker` before `$(function() {`? You can still call `setInterval` inside of it.

Comment: Yes thank you, i managed to sort it with your advice. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you defined `ticker` inside the `$()` bit, which means it's only available within the scope. Just defined it before then:

```
function ticker() {
   . . . 
}

$(function() {
  myTimer = setInterval(ticker, 10000);
});
```

I also got rid of the `var` before `myTimer` since you don't want define `myTimer` as a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to remove the function from the $function(){ and widen the scope.

A simple Solution really.

```
        $(function(){
        ticker();
        });


    function ticker() {


        var varLISTID = "<?php echo $listID; ?>";
        var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $useraccountname; ?>";
        var varITEMACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $itemaccountname; ?>";
        var varSELECTEDUSER=document.getElementById('datacatchuser').getAttribute("data-variable-SELECTEDUSER");


        var mybutton= "messageboxreplybutton.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
        $('#buttonbox').load(mybutton);

        var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
        $('#infobox1').load(mylink);

        var myotherlink = "contactselect.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER; 
        $('#containercontact').load(myotherlink);


 console.log("timer fired 2sec")
}

var myTimer = setInterval(ticker, 10000);






function editBuyermessage(messageid){


    var varmessageid=messageid;//the div holding the data var
                                var varmessageID = document.getElementById('Buyer'+varmessageid+'').getAttribute("data-variable-messageID");//the id in the database
                                var varMESSAGEDATE = document.getElementById('Buyer'+varmessageid+'').getAttribute("data-variable-MESSAGEDATE");//message's senders username 
                                    var varLISTID = "<?php echo $listID; ?>";
                                    var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $useraccountname; ?>";
                                    var varITEMACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $itemaccountname; ?>";
                                var varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('Buyer'+varmessageid+'').getAttribute("data-variable-MESSAGEACCOUNTNAME");//message's senders username 
                                var varSELECTEDUSER = document.getElementById('datacatchuser').getAttribute("data-variable-SELECTEDUSER");


            if (varUSERACCOUNTNAME==varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME){

                        var ebm=document.getElementById('editBuyer'+varmessageid+'');

                    if ( $(ebm).attr("contentEditable") == "false" ){
                    $('#editBuyer'+varmessageid+'').prop('contenteditable', true);
                    $('#editBuyer'+varmessageid+'').css('outline', '0px');
                    $('#editBuyer'+varmessageid+'').css('border', '1px dashed #07f310');
                    $('#boxBEDIT'+varmessageid+'').text('Save');
                                                                    console.log("Paused for Typing")
                                                                    clearInterval(myTimer);
                    }

                    else {
                    $('#editBuyer'+varmessageid+'').prop('contenteditable', false);
                    $('#editBuyer'+varmessageid+'').css('outline', '0px');
                    $('#editBuyer'+varmessageid+'').css('border', '1px solid transparent');
                    $('#boxBEDIT'+varmessageid+'').text('Edit');                    
                                                                    clearInterval(myTimer);
                                                                    myTimer = setInterval(ticker, 10000);
                                                                            console.log("Restart Timer")


                            var gotmessage = $('#editBuyer'+varmessageid+'').text();
                            var regex= /fuck|cunt|slag|bitch|fukker|nonce|prick|bollocks|dick|shag|slut|bastard|fuk|spunk|shit|wank/gi;
                            gotmessage=gotmessage.replace(regex, "****");                   
                            var Buyer="Buyer";

                                    if (gotmessage !="") {



                                                $.ajax({

                                                        url:"insertedit.php",
                                                         type: "POST",
                                                          dataType: 'text',
                                                          cache: false,

                                                            data:{
                                                                BuyerSeller:Buyer,
                                                                messageID:varmessageID,
                                                                messagesent:gotmessage,
                                                                listID:varLISTID,
                                                                messageDate:varMESSAGEDATE,
                                                                useraccountname:varUSERACCOUNTNAME,
                                                                },
                                                                    async: true,

                                                                    success:function(data){



                                                                        var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname="+ varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname="+ varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser="+ varSELECTEDUSER;
                                                                        $('#infobox1').load(mylink);

                                                                        var myotherlink = "contactselect.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER; 
                                                                        $('#containercontact').load(myotherlink);






                                                                        }
                                                });

                                    }// if gotmessage not empty
                                    else {
                                    alert('Empty Message - Not Sent');
                                    return false;
                                    }





                    }

            }

            else
            { alert("Sorry You Cannot Edit "+varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME+"'s Message!"); }



}



function editSellermessage(messageid){



    var varmessageid=messageid;//the div holding the data var

    var varmessageID = document.getElementById('Seller'+varmessageid+'').getAttribute("data-variable-messageID");//the id in the database
    var varMESSAGEDATE = document.getElementById('Seller'+varmessageid+'').getAttribute("data-variable-MESSAGEDATE");//message's senders username 
    var varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('Seller'+varmessageid+'').getAttribute("data-variable-MESSAGEACCOUNTNAME");//message's senders username 
    var varSELECTEDUSER=document.getElementById('datacatchuser').getAttribute("data-variable-SELECTEDUSER");
    var varLISTID = "<?php echo $listID; ?>";
    var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $useraccountname; ?>";
    var varITEMACCOUNTNAME = "<?php echo $itemaccountname; ?>";

            if (varUSERACCOUNTNAME==varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME){


                        var ebm=document.getElementById('editSeller'+varmessageid+'');

                    if ( $(ebm).attr("contentEditable") == "false" ){
                    $('#editSeller'+varmessageid+'').prop('contenteditable', true);
                    $('#editSeller'+varmessageid+'').css('outline', '0px');
                    $('#editSeller'+varmessageid+'').css('border', '1px dashed #07f310');
                    $('#boxSEDIT'+varmessageid+'').text('Save');
                                                                                console.log("Paused for Typing")
                                                                                clearInterval(myTimer);
                    }

                    else { //else save



                    $('#editSeller'+varmessageid+'').prop('contenteditable', false);
                    $('#editSeller'+varmessageid+'').css('outline', '0px');
                    $('#editSeller'+varmessageid+'').css('border', '1px solid transparent');
                    $('#boxSEDIT'+varmessageid+'').text('Edit');                    

                                                                        clearInterval(myTimer);
                                                                        myTimer = setInterval(ticker, 10000);
                                                                                            console.log("Restart Timer")


                            var gotmessage = $('#editSeller'+varmessageid+'').text();
                            var regex= /fuck|cunt|slag|bitch|fukker|nonce|prick|bollocks|dick|shag|slut|bastard|fuk|spunk|shit|wank/gi;
                            gotmessage=gotmessage.replace(regex, "****");                   
                            var Seller="Seller";

                                    if (gotmessage !="") {



                                                $.ajax({

                                                        url:"insertedit.php",
                                                         type: "POST",
                                                          dataType: 'text',
                                                          cache: false,

                                                            data:{
                                                                BuyerSeller:Seller,
                                                                messageID:varmessageID,
                                                                messagesent:gotmessage,
                                                                listID:varLISTID,
                                                                messageDate:varMESSAGEDATE,
                                                                useraccountname:varUSERACCOUNTNAME,
                                                                sendto:varSELECTEDUSER,
                                                                },
                                                                    async: true,

                                                                    success:function(data){


                                                                        var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname="+ varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
                                                                        $('#infobox1').load(mylink);


                                                                        }
                                                });

                                    }// if gotmessage not empty
                                    else {
                                    alert('Empty Message - Not Sent');
                                    return false;
                                    }





                    }

            }

            else
            { alert("Sorry You Cannot Edit "+varMESSAGEACCOUNTNAME+"'s Message!"); }



}
```